# Access 2007 Form Combo Box not accepting item from list

Tags: ms-access-2007

This is driving me mad! I have a relatively simple form  with just a table as its data source. On that table are two foreign keys to lookup tables which are editable via normal combo boxes which themselves have simple single table row sources. The form works perfectly well as a stand-alone popup form and as a sub-form.

However, when I open it from within another form and wait for the user to complete the edit using :

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ACCategory", , , , acFormEdit, , wargs

    Forms!ACCategory.SetFocus
    Do While CurrentProject.AllForms("ACCategory").IsLoaded
        Sleep 100
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

I cannot select values from the aforementioned combo boxes. There is logic within the form's On Load event which applies a filter and disables some unrelated controls but removing this code has no effect upon the outcome (apart, obviously,  from presenting the wrong record). I can edit other data on the form without any problem; it is just the combo boxes.

I've googled & tried all sorts of things but to no avail. I'm sure it's going to embarrassingly simple but I just can't see it and it is holding me up something terrible.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

...some additional info: Although I cannot select from the list in the combo boxes, I can type the values into the combo box and it finds & saves them. Most peculiar... I've also tried it without the DoEvents loop but the result is the same...

...more additional info: I've reworked my main form and simplified things a lot and created an even simpler version of the form with exactly the same result! I've tried un-binding the form from the table and doing all of the file work by hand (thus removing the filter) but it still isn't working. Surely I'm not alone in having found this problem?

...more info: I though it may have been a file buffering issue as I'm creating a default record which is created in the main form and passed to the troublesome form to be edited. It isn't, though; I've passed an existing record and that has the same problem. Perhaps it is calling a popup from a popup, both on a DoEvents loop? Who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I have traced the cause of the problem:

It is not easy to put into words but:

If a form invokes an second form within a DoEvents/Sleep loop and that second form invokes a third form from within another DoEvents/Sleep loop then combo boxes don't work properly in that third form.

I've redesigned the second form to include the third form as a SubForm on on a Tab Control and all is fine. It all needs tidying up a bit but it basically works.

Phew! What a marathon!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure everyone out there knows already, but I seem to have found another method to pause form execution while another form executes which doesn't used the DoEvents/Sleep loop. It works and it is simpler too:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "<YourFormName>", , , , , acDialog, wargs
```

"Zut alors!" as they say over here!